# Issue with react router dom's <Switch>

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I was using react router dom package and faced the issue with functionality of redericting the user to sign in page if there is no access token in local storage. Here is my current code:

```
<Switch>
              <Route
                exact
                path="/dashboard"
                render={() => {
                  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("accessToken")) ? (
                    <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
                  ) : (
                    <Redirect to="/sign-in" />
                  );
                }}
              />

              <Route
                exact
                path="/select-product"
                component={SelectProductPage}
              />
              <Route exact path="/" component={InitialPage} />
              <Route exact path="/sign-in" component={SignInPage} />
              <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
              <Route exact path="/sign-up" component={SignUpPage} />
              <Route
                exact
                path="/select-product"
                component={SelectProductPage}
              />
            </Switch>
```

The problem is that the functionality of redirection works as expected but the dashboard component is NOT rendered, that is, when a user is redirected to /dashboard, it is empty perhaps I made mistake with the order of routes. I need your help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are redirecting to a route that doesn't have any render , I think this will loop over render , so you have to just put your jsx component instead of redirect in case of logged user as below

```
<Route
     exact
     path="/dashboard"
     render={() => {
       return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("accessToken")) ? (
           <Dashboard /> {/* <---- here render your component dashboard */}
       ) : (
           <Redirect to="/sign-in" />
       );
     }}
/>
```